# What is the Krita equivalent to copy & paste?

Tags: krita, copy-and-paste

I am brand new to Krita. I opened an existing JPEG picture with Krita 4.17 and am unable to copy a door and paste it to make a second door in the picture. If I use the polygonal Selection Tool to encircle the area I want to duplicate, then hit <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it creates a layer. Then what?

Comment: Not a Krita user, but in 99.% of software CTRL+V means paste. If you haven't copied anything,there's usually nothing to paste. You need to CTRL+C to copy, *then* CTRL+V to paste in most application.

Comment: I've done that with no results. If I use the polygonal Selection Tool to encircle the area I want to duplicate, I can either right click and select, "Copy Selection to New Layer" or, while the highlighted area has the dashes going around it, key in CTRL + C, then CTRL+ V. Nothing seems to be copied because nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you have made a selection, pressed Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V and a new layer  appeared, the selected area is duplicated in the new layer. It's exactly the same as the original and in the same place, so the image is unchanged. Take the Move tool and move the copy to the wanted place.

Be sure you have the new layer selected in the layers panel before you use the Move tool. As well be sure that you have a non-empty layer selected when you press Ctrl+C

BTW: Getting automatically a new layer is something that users generally appreciate, because the original stays intact and one can easily test different edits without destroying the original.

Answer (score 0):

Krita works with different type of layers.

You worked in a **Paint** layer (as you opened an JPEG file). Pasting the selection from the clipboard is possible only

- as a new layer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to the same position, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to the position of cursor)
- as a new image (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

**There is not a possibility to paste it into the same layer, or into an existing layer.**

- *Note:*
  With **vector** layers the things are different: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> pastes the selection into *the same* layer, slightly shifted to the right and down from the original selection and automatically selects it.

So, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, there is seemly no change, but if you have opened the Layers docker (*Settings → Dockers → Layers*), you will see a new layer with the appended "(pasted)"  in its name.

- You see no difference in the image, because – as I wrote – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> pasted the selection in the exactly same position as the original selection, so both of them are perfectly aligned.
- But if you hover with the mouse on this new layer in the Layers docker, you will see a miniature of its content – the pasted part of your original image.

Now you may

- click to this new layer to make it an *active* layer,
- click on the “Transform a layer or a selection” tool [image] (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and

  - move your pasted selection by dragging it with mouse (out of the 9 handles),
  - resize it by dragging a handle,
  - rotate it or skew it by dragging near a handle,
  - 3-D rotate it with holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key,
  - … and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the portions of the image in the new layer at the correct position, just click the mouse right button and select "Merge with the layer below" and done.

Answer (score -2):

I’m unaware as to whether the problem has been resolved, but to copy and paste onto Krita is simple, just use edit to paste the image into a new layer, or go to layers and import a layer. If you import the layer then it will take you to your files and photos.
Krita automatically makes the image the same size as the photo, so after pasting an image onto Krita, if part of the image is not visible, just change the canvas size to make it bigger and you can see the full image.
Once this is done, you can edit the photo and change the size to however you see fit, and if you still require for the image to be a certain size, you can change the canvas size afterwards